# R to parse XML page

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML page http://www.thruway.ny.gov/xml/interchanges.xml.

I want to create a data frame with one interchange in each row, and id, latitude, etc. as columns.

I tried this to get nodes in a vector, and was planning to do similarly for other columns, and bind them into a dataframe. But the `getNodeSet` does not seem to work.

```
interchanges_xml <- xmlParse("http://www.thruway.ny.gov/xml/interchanges.xml")

id <- setNames(
  xmlToDataFrame(node = getNodeSet(interchanges_xml, "/interchanges/interchange/id")), 
  "id"
)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on 'does not seem to work'? do you get an error? Or can you explain the difference between what happens and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I find using the xml2 package easier to use than the XML.

```
library(xml2)
doc<-read_xml("http://www.thruway.ny.gov/xml/interchanges.xml")
nodes<- xml_find_all (doc, "interchange")
df<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, xml_attrs(nodes)))
```

Comment: thanks Dave2e. I could not find the function xml_nodes. I used xml_find_all and it worked.

Comment: Sorry about that, `xml_nodes` is a function in the rvest package which is an extension of xml2.  Yes, using `xml_find_all` is the proper syntax.